# Regex For Square Brackets with Quotes

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract all the entries from the following string:

```
[
"GUID_ID_ONE",
"2016-07-11T18:35:29Z",
"email@address.com",
"HASH_STRING",
"GUID_KEY_TWO",
"GUID_KEY_THREE"
]
```

I would like a RegEx to extract all the strings, quotes omitted. I have used

```
   "(.*?)"
```

but this would appear to only find the first string.

Comment: From which programming language or environment are you going to use the regular expression?

Comment: How are you currently implementing this and in what language? You may need to use a global flag `g` or a multi-line flag `m` to indicate you want to search for multiple instances within your string.

Comment: I would rather use a JSON parser to read the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the language you're using, the implementation can be different but you need to use the `global` modifier(`g`) to get all the matching strings, like this :

```
/"(.*?)"/g
```

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/oG2dO1/1)